# Magento Bundle Products Problem with the option to add new

Tags: bundle, products-view

Please help. I have a problem with the option to add new Bundle Items. He acts as if there is a limited add new option. When you add more than two options, going on the problem as the video:
http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c2f2j9ntaD

Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `max post size` is the issue. PHP limits the size of the POST array which is an issue with large bundled product selections.

For a bundled option item there are about 4 inputs so 50 options makes 200 inputs + all the other variables like the name, stock, images etc.

Edit your `PHP.ini` and increase the following values

> post_max_size=20M
>
> max_input_vars=1000